# How do I make sure a winform is garbage collected?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, garbage-collection, finalizer

As I learned from online and my personal experiment, the finalizer of a form (System.Windows.Forms.Form) never gets called by GC.
It is said that inside the Dispose() of Form GC.SuppressFinalize() is called so that finalizer wouldn't gets called again.

Exapmle:

```
public partial class UpdateForm : Form
{
    public UpdateForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Listen to the event of some model
        Database.OnDataUpdated += new EventHandler(DataBase_OnDataUpdated);
    }

    ~UpdateForm()
    {
        // Never gets called.
    }

    private void DataBase_OnDataUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update data on this form
    }
}
```

However, as the example above shows, if the form connects(+=) a event of some model and doesn't disconnect(-=) the event in Dispose(), the form would never be garbage collected, even if the Dispose() gets called.

What I do to check if the form is really garbage collected is that I create a big array inside the form to consume a lot of memory as below:

```
 int[] dummyArray = new int[1024 * 1024 * 128]; // Comsume 128MB memory
```

Then I look at the Memory Profile of Task Manager in Windows to see if the memory usage is reduced when I call GC.Collect() after the form is disposed.

My method is not smart, and I wonder if there is other smarter way or some tools to confirm the form is actually garbage collected? Thanks.

Comment: The form still gets garbage collected even if the finalizer doesn't get called. But why would you want the finalizer to be called? What could you put in the finalizer that you *shouldn't* put in the `Dispose` method?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I didn't mean I want the finalizer gets called. I just want to make sure the form is garbage collected, i.e. all the memory the form uses should be released. I usually use finalizer to examine if a object is actually garbage collected which cannot be done with form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a weak reference to your form using the [WeakReference class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx):

```
var weakref = new WeakReference(form);
```

A weak reference does not prevent the object from being garbage collected, and you can use that property to check if it has been:

```
if (weakref.IsAlive) { /* not yet garbage collected */ }
```

The form does not need a finalizer for this to work.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for: a general method to detect whether a object(not necessarily a form) is still alive. Now I wonder taking form as example might be misleading.

Comment: I did some experiments using WeakReference as above. I observed that the form was NOT garbage collected when there is no other reference to the form, even after calling GC.Collect(). My guess is that the WeakReference decideds whether the form can be garbage collected. Therefore, there is no guarantee the form will be garbage collected right after calling GC.Collect().

Comment: @Paul20 No, a WeakReference never prevents the object (form) from being garbage collected. If you can put up a short example that reliably shows a form not being garbage collected even though according to you it should be, I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: ok, it's an old question, btw for future readers, be sure that your form doesn't have delegates to other forms/controls that are still alive, because when you register to another form/control event, the publisher (the control that expose the event) hold a reference to the callee, so your form still have a reference that keep him alive and not collectable. To solve those issues i suggest to use an EventAggregator and expose/consume events using that

Answer (score 3):

```
    Database.OnDataUpdated += new EventHandler(DataBase_OnDataUpdated);
```

Yes, that's a problem.  The generic diagnostic is that the event source object out-lives the event listener object.  Or in other words, your form object keeps listening to database updates, even after it was closed by the user.  This usually causes an exception, the most typical way in which you discover the problem, boilerplate is an ObjectDisposedException when your event handler tries to update the disposed controls.  It isn't that clear how you managed to avoid this failure mode, do make sure you didn't paper-over that failure mode with, say, a try/catch.

And, yes, it causes a GC problem.  The Database object has a reference to your form object.  You gave it that reference when you subscribed the event.  And uses it again, later, when it fires the event.  Necessary because your DataBase_OnDataUpdated() method is an instance method of your class.  The C# syntax sugar hides that fact.  The actual code underneath that simple event assignment statement looks like this (not valid C# code):

```
var delegateObject = new EventHandler(this, &DataBase_OnDataUpdated);
Database.OnDataUpdated = Delegate.Combine(DataBase_OnDataUpdated, delegateObject);
```

It is the hidden *this* in the delegate constructor call that passes the reference to your form object to the Database object.  Which stores it in the Delegate.Target field.  To be used later when it fires the event.

So, inevitably, the GC sees a reference to your form object even after it is closed.  It finds it back in the delegate invocation list of the Database object.  So the form object cannot be garbage collected until the Database object is garbage collected.  Which, judging from your question, doesn't happen until your program terminates.  Probably because it is a static variable.

There are other patterns that avoid this problem.  You could for example pass a reference to your form to the Database class, which can store it in a list of active forms that are listening to notifications.  It can subscribe the form's Disposed event to know that the form is dead and remove the object from that list.  You'd also need to have your form implement an interface, methods that the Database class calls when something interesting happens.  The antipode of the observer pattern, otherwise not exactly as pretty as using events.

Or just punt the problem, since you now know what causes it.  Simply unsubscribe the event explicitly:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        Database.OnDataUpdated -= DataBase_OnDataUpdated;
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }
```

Note how this exact same kind of code is required when you subscribe to other event sources in .NET that outlive their listeners.  Like the events raised by SystemEvents and Application.Idle

Comment: From how I read the question, the OP already knows where to unsubscribe the event, and is merely looking for a way to confirm that that does indeed fix the problem (that no other references prevent the form from being garbage collected). In fact, unsubscribing in Dispose() as the OP mentions is probably better than in OnFormClosed(), since Dispose() typically gets called even if an exception is thrown before the form is shown. You've put up a (very) well-written answer, but I think an answer to a slightly different question.

Comment: @Hans: Thank you very much for your detailed and useful answer. I did learn several new things from it. However hvd's answer is closer to what I tried to look for. Sorry that I might not explain my question clearly.